# Can the element reference in an AngularJS directive cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, angularjs-directive

In an AngularJS directive, does it make sense to set the element reference to `undefined` in case you've used it?

In other words, can using the element reference cause a memory leak? We're currently profiling our application and I'm trying to find out why we have memory leaks.

For example let's say I wan't to check whether the element is visible before invoking some functionality:

```
module.directive("myDir", function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.$watch(function(){
                return element.is(":visible");
            }, function(isElementVisible){
                if(isElementVisible){
                    // do something ...
                }
            }
        } 
    };
});
```

Would this cause a leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICS this does *not* create any memory leak.
When the element gets removed, the scope is destroyed, the watch is removed, the function is no longer referenced.

As a micro optimization (which you shouldn't really bother with) if you only want to execute some code only once, when the element gets visible, then you can remove the watch manually.
(scope.$watch() returns a function that you can call to remove the watch.)